# Raster values appear in table but not on display

Tags: display

I applied weighted overlay on certain rasters and it resulted in a raster which has attribute table but not all of those value appear on display. Below is my values from table, I put maroon color so it would be significantly visible but it just doesn't show
[image: this is the display of my raster]

[image: these are the values in table]

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Have you had a look at the histogram of the raster? How many pixels of 9 are there supposed to be?

Comment: There's only 322 pixels for value 9 and others are in thousands, apparently that's the reasons 9 is not visible. But is there any way to locate/identify 9 on display?